# Mono + XSP: WebService example does not work

Tags: c#, web-services, mono, debian, xsp

There have been questions quite similar to this one, but I could not find any solution. So excuse me for asking it again.

I'm running Debian Linux and I installed Mono. Once I started the [sample WebService](http://www.mono-project.com/Writing_a_WebService) with the XSP (or XSP4) server, I can not access it neither locally nor from anywhere else in the network.

The *.asmx file is in a folder from which I also start the XSP server.

Here's the sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace MathService
{
    [WebService (Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/NumberService")]
    public class MathService : WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public int AddNumbers (int number1, int number2)
        {
            return number1 + number2;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public int SubtractNumbers (int number1, int number2)
        {
            return number1 - number2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because the current Debian Wheezy operating system for the Raspberry Pi is supporting some hard-float features of the ARM processor. But some Java/.NET application needs soft-float. This is why they might crash. There is a soft-float version of the operating system called Raspbian Wheezy but it is not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look out for soft-float versions of your operation system or a mono version that supports hard-float. See [this link](http://ayvazyan.net/2013/12/mono-3-2-7-is-working-on-a-raspberry-pi-running-raspbian-hard-float/).